# how to declare an array of mutable lists and populate lists with starting values

Tags: kotlin

I want to create an array of mutable lists, and each mutable list should have a specified number of ints. These ints should have a starting value of `0`.

Example: I know the number of mutable lists, `n`, in the array, and I know how many integers, `m` are in each list. I think I can declare the array like so:

```
// represents number of mutable lists in the array
val n = 2
// represents number of Ints inside each mutable list
val m = 3

val arr = Array<MutableList<Int>>(n) { ??? }
```

What this should do is it should create an Array `arr` that contains only the type `MutableList`. The array is of size `n`. The mutable lists take in only the type `Int`.

I am not sure how to iterate through these mutable lists and add `m` number of `0` valued integers.

Comment: The `{ ??? }` lambda will be called for each index (`0 until n`) and has to return a `MutableList<Int>`. Inside the lambda you can create your own `MutableList` instance and call `add(0)` on it exactly `m` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) `(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)`

> The function `init` is called for each array element sequentially starting from the first one. It should return the value for an array element given its index.

Same for [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html)

```
// represents number of mutable lists in the array
val n = 2
// represents number of Ints inside each mutable list
val m = 3

val arr = Array(n) { MutableList(m) { 0 } }
```

Comment: This is so simple that I feel silly for asking -- but it's all clicking now. Thanks